# Can't access my 2d array f#

Tags: arrays, f#

I have just started programing on f# (or anything else), so this question may seem kindda basic. I am doing a proyect that came with a library, and i am trying to use a 2D string array that came in the library.  The array is of type string[][]. I need to access each one of the bases so I figured i would do something like the following:

```
    let humanos = interfaz.GetArregloHumanos()
    Array2D.getbase1 humanos
```

interfaz.getArregloHumanos() is a function that comes with the library that is supposed to return the array of type string [][]
it looks as if humanos is not being recogniced as han array, can somenoe tell me why?

Comment: I don't understand your question - are you asking how you can access the arrays elements in F#? (it's just `humanos.[x].[y]`)

Comment: I tried that, but it isnt working either.

Answer (score 2):

There is an important difference between array of arrays of type `string[][]` and two-dimensional array of type `string[,]`. A 2D array is a rectangular 2D array, while array of arrays is simply an array that contains `string[]` arrays as elements (each of them can be of different length).

The functions from the `Array2D` module work with 2D arrays, while your library seems to be returning an array of arrays.

A simple example doing something with array of arrays would look like this:

```
let strs =
  [| [| "hi"; "there" |]
     [| "just one thing" |] |]

for nested in strs do
  printfn "---------"
  for s in nested do
    printfn " - %s" s
```

For more information see:

- [The MSDN documentation for F# arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx)
- [The F# Wikibooks article on arrays](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Arrays)

Comment: any suggestions why humanos.[0][1] for example, doesnt work on my array?

Comment: You need a dot to perform indexing into the second array too: `humanos.[0].[1]`